# mysql opposite of foreign key

Tags: mysql, key

I have 2 tables, customers and affiliates. I need to make sure that customers.email and affiliates.email are exclusive. In other words, a person cannot be both a customer and an affiliate. It's basically the opposite of a foreign key. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You can use a table that stores emails and have unique constrain on the email, and reference that table from the customer and affiliate.</strike> (still need to ensure that there are no 2 records referencing the same key)

You can use trigger before insert and before update to check if the email is not present.

Or you can leave this validation to the application logic - not in the database, but in the applicationc ode.

Comment: How would your first solution prevent the customers table and the affiliates table from both referencing a single record in the table of emails?

Comment: Yes, I agree with octern. But the second part of your answer is legit. Leaving it to the application logic (running a check before inserting a new record) seems to be the easiest way. Edit your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no key you can do this with, but it sounds like you shouldn't be using two tables.  Instead, you can have one table with either customer/affiliate data (that needs to be unique in this table) and another table that has the type (customer/affiliate).

```
CREATE TABLE People (
   pplid,
   pplEmail,
   ptid,
   UNIQUE KEY (pplEmail)
)
CREATE TABLE PeopleType (
   ptid,
   ptType
)
INSERT INTO PeopleType VALUES (1, 'affiliates'), (2, 'customers');
```

Comment: While it's not quite as normalized, you could also have a column in the table that is 0 for customer and 1 for affiliate.

Comment: @Fls'Zen that is more or less the same (you could also use an `enum` for instance).  Depends on how normal you want to be :)

Comment: You've basically combined customers and affiliates into one table (people). Problem is that customers and affiliates have very different fields, so this doesn't really work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following.
Create a new table, which will be a master for customers and affiliates:

```
CREATE TABLE party
( 
  id int not null auto_increment primary key ,
  party_type enum('customer','affiliate') not null,
  email varchar(100),
  UNIQUE (id,party_type)
);
--Then
CREATE TABLE customer
(
   ....
   party_id INT NOT NULL,
   party_type enum('customer') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'customer',
   PRIMARY KEY (party_id,party_type)
   FOREIGN KEY (party_id,party_type) REFERENCES party(id,party_type)
);
CREATE TABLE affiliates
(
   ....
   party_id INT NOT NULL,
   party_type enum('affiliate') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'affiliate',
   PRIMARY KEY (party_id,party_type)
   FOREIGN KEY (party_id,party_type) REFERENCES party(id,party_type)
)
-- enum is used because mysql still doesn't have CHECK constraints
```

This way each party can be only of one type